# jquery find div within nested div containers

Tags: jquery, find, children

I am trying to get the text or html of a div container that is nested within another div container. jquery code returns undefined.  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bitcoder/f3gccua9/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="todo-task ui-draggable-handle ui-sortable-handle" id="29,Action" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="task-header">
     <div class="task-no">29</div>
     <div class="task-type">Action</div>
  </div>
  <div class="task-body">
     <div class="task-title">Review the detailed project management plan</div>
  </div>
  <div class="task-footer">
     <div class="task-date"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:12px">access_time</i>&nbsp;Jun 20</div>
     <div class="task-Username">GV</div>
  </div>
```

Here is the jquery code I am trying

```
var html = $('#29,Action').children().find('.task-body').html();
console.log(html);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why do you have `,` in your id you can use `_` if you really want to have something to distinguish number from letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your id names. You cannot begin with a number, or use a comma. see [the rules here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/id-html-attribute/). use `id='Action-27'` , then:

```
 var html = $('#Action-27').find('.task-body').html();
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/f3gccua9/5/)